# Google TV - Can I do pairing without the challenge?

Tags: google-tv

I've been using the new YouTube capability with my GTV box and am quite jealous of its ability to pair my phone to the box without a challenge. Obviously, this is something baked into the two YouTube apps, but I'm wondering if there are plans to allow the same kind of unchallenged pairing for developers' second screen apps.

If not, I'm wondering if there's a way to allow a user to re-pair the phone's app to the GTV device in subsequent sessions (for example, sometimes I'll successfully log in, but my app will drop the connection) without having to go through the annoyance of the challenge. I did find this as an answer in another thread:

> It could remember the device IP, but you would have to click on the IP
>   address and re-establish the pairing session. Basically once the
>   connection is lost, it needs to re-authenticate itself ( thats
>   pairing) to establish new connection. – Megha Joshi - GoogleTV DevRel 
>   Jun 21 at 20:45

So in that case, would I have to write an app for the Google TV that would remember the device IP in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sebastian Kaspari wrote a nice library called [Android-Network-Intents](https://github.com/pocmo/Android-Network-Intents).

It shows you how to send Android Intent objects to listening apps/devices via multicast (UDP).

Answer (score 1):

For the official Google TV Remote app and for the Able Remote app, once you have paired successfully with a device, subsequent connections will not require the explicit pairing step. Both apps also remember the last connected device, so re-starting the apps should make them automatically connect.

If you are a developer and using the Anymote Library that Google open sourced (https://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/browse/#git%2FAnymoteLibrary), then that library requires that the pairing step be done with every connection.

The Anymote-for-Java library that I open-sourced (https://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/browse/#git%2FAnymoteLibrary) will remember the pairing information and only requires the pairing step to be done once per device.

The new protocol that the YouTube apps are using has not been made available to third-party app developers.